# bodyParser.json() doesn't decode deep?

Tags: json, node.js, http, express, decode

I use `bodyParser.json()` to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` request, but i find `req.body` object doesn't decoded deep, it's like:

```
 var a = {
  total: '143.0',
  delivery_time: '0',
  utime: '1461302812',
  wm_poi_name: '%E5%B9%B8%E7%A6%8F%E8%A5%BF%E9%A5%BC'
};
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: As I know x-www-form-urlencoded don't allow nested data, you have to encode wm_poi_name to a json string and decode it on your controller